# Why is $\bar{B^t} \bar{A^t} = \overline{(AB)^t}$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

In class I've encountered the following thing: $\bar{B^t} \bar{A^t} = \overline{(AB)^t}$.

I don't understand why that's true.

Comment: Are $A,B$ matrices? (If so, remove the tag group theory). What is $\overline{\cdot}$? Is it an element-wise conjugate? Is $t$ transpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my assumptions about your notation are correct, 
$$
\overline{(AB)^{t}}\equiv\overline{(B^{t}A^{t})}=\overline{B^{t}}\,\overline{A^{t}}.
$$
You should check that $(AB)^{t}=B^{t}A^{t}$ and $\overline{AB}=\overline{A}\,\overline{B}$ for any two matrices $A,B$ to establish the above.

**Hint**: use the definition of matrix-matrix product.